# Is there a way of getting a Mac's icon given its model number?

Tags: macos, cocoa, multipeer-connectivity, airdrop

I know you can get the current machine's icon from cocoa using the following code:

```
NSImage *machineIcon = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameComputer];
```

But is it possible to get the icon when given just a model number? Such as `MacBookPro11,3`?

The reason I need this is because I'm using `MultiPeer Connectivity` to browse devices on the network that I'd like to connect to. But I want to display the icons from those devices in a customized browser view.

I know that OS X has pretty much every icon for all the devices in the following folder:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/
```

but I want to know how to get access to them from within my app:

I thought about using the `discoveryInfo` from `MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser` to transmit an icon of the device advertising, but you can't transmit that much data using `discoveryInfo`. It's designed only for small amounts of text. So I've decided to just transmit the machine's model number instead. I'm hoping to resolve the machine's model number to an icon on the other side. Kind of like how `AirDrop` does it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Mac App Store safe

Manually map model identifier to icon name and then use e.g

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:@"com.apple.macbookair"];
```

or

```
 [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameComputer]
```

If you need higher resolution than imageNamed provides use

```
  OSType code = UTGetOSTypeFromString((CFStringRef)CFSTR("root"));
  NSImage *computer = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(code)];
```

where "root" string is from IconsCore.h header file (kComputer).

Copy this plist to get the identifiers (do not access it from app sandbox)

> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerInformation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/SIMachineAttributes.plist

2. Mac App Store unsafe

Link Private Framework SPSupport.Framework with your binary
Add FrameWork Search path variable

> $(SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR)/PrivateFrameworks

Add following interface into your project

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface SPDocument : NSDocument

- (NSImage *)modelIcon;
- (id)computerName;
- (id)serialNumber;
- (id)modelName;

@end
```

Call in your code:

```
  SPDocument *document = [[SPDocument alloc] init];
  NSImage *icon = [document modelIcon];
```

3. Hardest way

Figure out CoreFoundation dance with this private function (this code is illustration, find correct types, number of params and release properly)

> ```
>   output = _LSCreateDeviceTypeIdentifierWithModelCode((CFStringRef)@"MacBookPro6,2");
>   NSImage *image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType: output];
> ```

**EDIT:**
I just realized that you need option number 1,3 (icon for given model). GL fighting this.

**EDIT2**
Method 3 added. Changed the order and added under number 1.

**EDIT3**
New UTIs for the colored version
com.apple.macbook-retina-silver
com.apple.device-model-code
MacBook8,1@ECOLOR=225,225,223

com.apple.macbook-retina-gold
com.apple.device-model-code
MacBook8,1@ECOLOR=235,215,191

com.apple.macbook-retina-space-gray
com.apple.device-model-code
MacBook8,1@ECOLOR=155,158,159
MacBook8,1@ECOLOR=157,157,160

NSImage *image =[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:@"com.apple.macbook-retina-gold"];

How to get model number/identifier (sysctl hw.model was replaced by system_profiler)?

```
NSPipe *outputPipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/sbin/system_profiler"];
[task setArguments:@[@"SPHardwareDataType"]];
[task setStandardOutput:outputPipe];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
NSData *outputData = [[outputPipe fileHandleForReading] readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *hardware = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:outputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And parse Model identifier or your propertylistserialization

Comment: Hmm... Well the trouble is that I need to be able to submit to the Mac App Store. So this would be problematic for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to programmatically convert model identifiers to images without using private frameworks. This code works on at least OS X 10.4 and later.

```
 + (NSImage*)imageForMachineModel:(NSString*)machineModel
 {
     NSImage* image = nil;

     NSString* uti = NULL;
     if ((machineModel != nil) &&
         ([machineModel length] > 0))
     {
         NSString* fixedModel = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machineModel.UTF8String];
         uti = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(CFSTR("com.apple.device-model-code"),(__bridge CFStringRef)fixedModel,NULL);
     }
     else
     {
         // Default to a generic Mac image for null
         uti = (__bridge_transfer NSString*) CFStringCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault,CFSTR("com.apple.mac"));
     }

     if (uti != NULL)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef utiDecl = UTTypeCopyDeclaration((__bridge CFStringRef)(uti));
         if (utiDecl != NULL)
         {
             CFStringRef iconFileName = CFDictionaryGetValue(utiDecl,CFSTR("UTTypeIconFile"));
             if (iconFileName == NULL)
             {
                 while((iconFileName == NULL) &&
                       (utiDecl != NULL) &&
                       (uti != NULL))
                 {
                     // BUG: macOS 10.12 may return string or array of strings; unchecked in this implementation!
                     uti = NULL;
                     uti = CFDictionaryGetValue(utiDecl,CFSTR("UTTypeConformsTo"));
                     if (uti != NULL)
                     {
                         CFRelease(utiDecl);
                         utiDecl = NULL;
                         utiDecl = UTTypeCopyDeclaration((__bridge CFStringRef)(uti));
                         if (utiDecl != NULL)
                         {
                             iconFileName = CFDictionaryGetValue(utiDecl,CFSTR("UTTypeIconFile"));
                         }
                     }
                 }
             }

             if (iconFileName != NULL)
             {
                 CFURLRef bundleURL = UTTypeCopyDeclaringBundleURL((__bridge CFStringRef)(uti));
                 if (bundleURL != NULL)
                 {
                     NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[(__bridge NSURL*)bundleURL path]];
                     if (bundle != nil)
                     {
                         NSString* iconPath = [bundle pathForResource:(__bridge NSString*)iconFileName ofType:nil];
                         if (iconPath != nil)
                         {
                             image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:iconPath];
                         }
                     }
                     CFRelease(bundleURL);
                 }
             }

             if (utiDecl != NULL)
             {
                 CFRelease(utiDecl);
             }
         }
     }

     if (image == nil)
     {
         // Do something sensible if no image found
     }

     return image;
 }
```

Be aware there is currently a bug `rdr://27883672` in macOS 10.12 beta 6 that crashes within `UTTypeCopyDeclaration`. This is because `UTTypeConformsTo` may return either a `CFStringRef` or `CFArrayRef` of `CFStringRef`. The code snippet assumes only a `CFStringRef` will ever be returned.

### Adapt for Sandboxing

To use this code with sandboxing, avoid directly loading the icon file. Instead get the `UTTypeIdentifier` from `utiDecl` and pass that to `NSWorkspace`'s `iconForFileType`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in Swift, but it uses a private API so remember that it might be subject to undocumented change and App Store rejection.

```
struct MachineAttributes {

    let privateFrameworksURL = "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerInformation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/SIMachineAttributes.plist"

    var model: String?

    var attributes: [String:AnyObject]?

    var iconPath: String?

    init() {
        self.model = getModel()
        self.attributes = getAttributes()
        self.iconPath = getIconPath()
    }

    init(model: String) {
        self.model = model
        self.attributes = getAttributes()
        self.iconPath = getIconPath()
    }

    private func getModel() -> String? {
        let service: io_service_t = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"))
        let cfstr = "model" as CFString
        if let model = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, cfstr, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? NSData {
            if let nsstr = NSString(CString: UnsafePointer<Int8>(model.bytes), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                return String(nsstr)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    private func getAttributes() -> [String:AnyObject]? {
        if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: privateFrameworksURL) as? [String:AnyObject],
            let id = model,
            let result = dict[id] as? [String:AnyObject] {
                return result
        }
        return nil
    }

    private func getIconPath() -> String? {
        if let attr = self.attributes, let path = attr["hardwareImageName"] as? String {
            return path
        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

If you don't know the model:

```
let myMachine = MachineAttributes()
if let model = myMachine.model {
    print(model)
}
if let iconPath = myMachine.iconPath {
    print(iconPath)
}
```

> MacBookPro9,2
>
> /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/com.apple.macbookpro-15-unibody.icns

If you know the model or want to use another one:

```
let myNamedMachine = MachineAttributes(model: "iMac14,2")
if let iconPath = myNamedMachine.iconPath {
    print(iconPath)
}
```

> /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/com.apple.imac-unibody-27-no-optical.icns

Comment: This is great. But I definitely need to be able to submit to the Mac App Store. I wonder if my best bet is to just copy that file into my app's bundle and also all the icons and distribute it like that? Apple may reject it for copyright violations though for using their icons. If new models come out I can just have a generic icon for the machine type. E.g. parse out "MacBook" or "MacPro" from the model and pick an icon that matches.

Comment: It also occurred to me that AirDrop doesn't actually use the machine's icon. It uses the login account's icon. I'll have to do some more investigating.

Comment: You are loosing time with details. Ship it first. BTW nice solution (but again requires access outside of sandbox app bundle to get the icon).

Comment: Hmm, no such "hardwareImageName" key for every model id I've tested. Running 10.11.6 (15G31)

Comment: Disclaimer: this system plist does not contain this info anymore, Apple changed it and I don't know where to find it now. This answer only works for OS X versions before El Capitan.