# Dictionary from Plist gives inconsistent results with same key

Tags: swift, cocoa

Inspired by this question:

[Is there a way of getting a Mac's icon given its model number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370037/is-there-a-way-of-getting-a-macs-icon-given-its-model-number)

I was working around getting similar results but using the Mac's model identifier as a start, not the Mac's model number.

*But I'm stuck with a weird problem when using my Mac's model identifier to find the related system icon.*

---

On my office machine I get **"iMac14,2"** as a model identifier.

When I load this plist as a dictionary...

> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerInformation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/SIMachineAttributes.plist

...I see that it has keys for all Mac models, including "iMac14,2", and the values contain, among other things, the URL for the icon.

However, when I try to grab this dictionary's value for the identifier key ("iMac14,2") I got `nil`, although I get the actual value if I grab it with a literal key.

But the literal key and the key I get from my `modelIdentifier` function are the same. It looks like it anyway...

---

To grab the model identifier:

```
func modelIdentifier() -> String? {
    let service: io_service_t = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice").takeUnretainedValue())
    let cfstr = "model" as CFString
    if let model = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(service, cfstr, kCFAllocatorDefault, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? NSData {
        if let nsstr =  NSString(data: model, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            return String(nsstr)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

if let id = modelIdentifier() {
    println(id) // prints "iMac14,2"
}
```

Finding the value with this result fails:

```
if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ServerInformation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/English.lproj/SIMachineAttributes.plist") as? [String:AnyObject] {

    if let id = modelIdentifier() {
        if let result = dict[id] as? [String:AnyObject] {
            print(result) // nil
        }
    }

}
```

But if I do the same with a literal string it works:

```
if let result = dict["iMac14,2"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
    print(result)
}
```

`result`:

> [architecture: x86_64, *LOCALIZABLE*: {
>       description = "iMac with 27\" widescreen LED-backlit display, introduced late 2013.";
>       marketingModel = "27\" iMac (Late 2013)";
>       model = iMac;
>       processor = "Quad-core Intel Core i5, Quad-core Intel Core i7";
>   }, hardwareImageName: /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/com.apple.imac-unibody-27-no-optical.icns]

---

What is wrong here?

The strings look the same but aren't the same?

Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSData` created by `IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty` for the `model` key contains a NUL-terminated string. You're including that NUL in your `NSString`.

Create your string this way instead:

```
    if let nsstr = NSString(CString: UnsafePointer<Int8>(model.bytes), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        return String(nsstr)
    }
```