# How to get current Mac model image

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

guys!

One of my views should contain the image of the Mac on which the program is running. It should look like in "About this Mac" window.
[image]

These images keeps somewhere in system and the question is how to get it programmatically? Objective-C.

I have code that simply substitutes the final image according to the current model, but I need the image loads from the system.

I shall be grateful for any help.

Comment: Are the images in your project's Images.xcassets file? because that's important.

Comment: OP wants to grab the system-used images from the OS itself.

Comment: Right, I want to grab the system-used images from the OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
[NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameComputer]
```

For other models look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32370037/is-there-a-way-of-getting-a-macs-icon-given-its-model-number/32373977#32373977)

Edit:
To get higher sizes use following:

```
  OSType code = UTGetOSTypeFromString((CFStringRef)CFSTR("root"));
  NSImage *computer = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFileType:NSFileTypeForHFSTypeCode(code)];
```

where "root" string is from IconsCore.h header file (kComputer).

Comment: That's not true at all.  See the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/System_Entity_Images) (search for "System Entity Images") for a preview of what you are suggesting.

Comment: Fix your question title then ;)

Comment: I don't have a question ;)

Comment: I am sorry but you are wrong, I just verified this in xcode. It gives you current model

Comment: Hmmm, interesting.  I will remove downvote.  According the class reference that just returns "A computer icon".  There is no mention of it being "the current mac model".  Oh well.

Comment: Sometimes the documentation lacks behinds framework. It happens especially with new APIs. Things are described in headers but not in documentation

Comment: Yes! The solution is    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameComputer];

Comment: Thanks a lot to  Marek and all involved!!

Comment: Nice. But it returns a 32x32 icon, not the hi-res one similar to "About this Mac".

Comment: Updated the answer to generate larger icons.