# Get the macbook/device color programmatically

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I would like to detect the color of the user device to associate it an image of the actual device (eg : Macbook SpaceGray or Gold).

I found a private API to do it with iOS devices but is there a way to do it (legally if possible) with OSX?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the API to do this in iOS please ?

Comment: Of course : http://www.futuretap.com/blog/device-colors/

Comment: If the OS provides the model number (eg. MK4N2LL/A, etc.) then it should be easy; although something tells me this is the crucial missing ingredient.

Comment: You are right, however I think getting these types of informations is not "legal".

Comment: Still a private API, but with my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32381289/2227743 you can get the Mac's icon, model, and other attributes.

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to send it to the app store.

Comment: Have you got the solution....

Comment: I'm sorry but no.. :(