# Get NSImage of current device

Tags: swift, nsimage

macOS comes with a bunch of predefined images (Folder, Trash, ...)
I can use the NSImage(named: "") here to get the image.

It looks like some of the images are stored in /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/

There are also images of all the Apple devices. Is there a way to get the images using Swift? I tried using the filename with NSImage(named: ""), but nil is returned.

Comment: `NSImage(named: NSImageNameComputer)` is the standard way of getting the machine icon. There used to be a way to easily get higher resolutions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32381289/2227743, but it doesn't work anymore. The not easy way should still work, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32373977/2227743.

Comment: Wow, that was easy, thank you. The image that is returned with the first method seems pretty high resolution to me, so I'll stick with that one.

Comment: Cool! You're welcome. I'm closing this question as a duplicate of the other one, since this is where I got this method from (Marek's answer).

Comment: Can I get the folder icons of the "Library", "User" and "Applications" folder in a similar way?

Comment: Available ones are listed here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage.name But I don't see the ones you want. So, the answer is no (or rather: I don't think so).

Comment: I also found the constant "kApplicationsFolderIcon" but I don't know how/where to use it.

Comment: No constant, but you can get a specific folder icon by giving its path: `NSWorkspace.shared().icon(forFile: "/Applications")`.